# How to format VBA code to 80 columns?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-formatting

I have some VBA code where lines are long and want to send it somewhere, where is (not 100% strict) limit 80 chars on line.

VBA allows to create to break line of code by placing " `_`" before "`enter`". (Obviously, this doesn't work inside strings, which must be splitted into substrings and connected with "`&`". As you can see below.)

Is there some tool to add "linebreaks" into code automatically?
Or maybe regex?

I tried to search, but no valid results.

Original code:

```vb
'Some looooooong comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a volutpat dolor. In risus odio, pharetra a arcu in, efficitur ornare lectus. Maecenas non aliquet leo. Praesent luctus blandit magna, et sagittis ex porta et.
MsgBox("Some text in MsgBox. Donec vulputate eros ac nulla hendrerit auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin fermentum augue elit, eget consequat massa mattis et. Integer semper imperdiet diam sit amet malesuada.", 64, "Title of MsgBox")
'Another comment now with link to doc. https://example.com/?bs64=SWYgeW91IGFyZSBzbWFydCBlbm91Z2ggdG8gZGVjb2RlLCB5b3UgbXVzdCBkZWZpbml0ZWx5IHdhdGNoIHRoaXM6IGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9b0hnNVNKWVJIQTA=
```

Wanted code:

```vb
'Some looooooong comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
'elit. Ut a volutpat dolor. In risus odio, pharetra a arcu in, efficitur
'ornare lectus. Maecenas non aliquet leo. Praesent luctus blandit magna, et
'sagittis ex porta et.
MsgBox("Some text in MsgBox. Donec vulputate eros ac nulla hendrerit auctor." _
 & "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin fermentum augue elit, eget " _ 
 & "consequat massa mattis et. Integer semper imperdiet diam sit amet" _
 & " malesuada.", 64, "Title of MsgBox")
'Another comment now with link to doc.
'https://example.com/?bs64=SWYgeW91IGFyZSBzbWFydCBlbm91Z2ggdG8gZGVjb2RlLCB5b3UgbXVzdCBkZWZpbml0ZWx5IHdhdGNoIHRoaXM6IGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9b0hnNVNKWVJIQTA=
```

Thanks.

PS: I'm using Notepad++

Comment: This is something you'll have to do manually. Its a one-time only thing unless you are copying code from elsewhere and want to make that readable. In either case, it will be benefitial if you go through the code yourself and format it properly. Not only will you understand the code better, you can format it like you want anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use two regex search and replace functions? One to only handle lines with a comment and the other will handle lines with a MsgBox. This would leave regular VBA alone. The first pattern could be:

```
^[^'].*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?:.{1,70}|.{71,140}|.{141,210}|.{211,280})|\G(?!^))\S+\K\h(?=.{25,}$)
```

Replace with  `\n'`, see the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VMEk5X/9)

---

The second one:

```
^(?!MsgBox\().*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?:.{1,70}|.{71,140}|.{141,210}|.{211,280})|\G(?!^))\S+\K\h(?=.{25,}$)
```

Replace with  `" _\n & "`, see the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VMEk5X/10)

---

A breakdown of the principles of the pattern:

- `^` - Start line ancor.
- `[^']` - Match any character but a literal single quote.
- `.*` - Match any character other than newline zero or more times.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - Skip/Fail combination to consume the matched pattern but negate it later.
- `|` - Alternation/OR.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group.

  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group.

    - `.{1,70}|.{71,140}|.{141,210}|.{211,280}` - Alternation to match any character other than newline an x amount of times. You could add more if your string values are even longer.
    - `)` - Close nested 2nd non-capture group.
  - `|` - Alternation/OR.
  - `\G(?!^)` - Assert position at end of previous match with negative lookahead to prevent start of string position.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capturing group.
- `\S+` - Match at least 1 non whitespace character.
- `\K` - Reset starting point of previous reported match.
- `\h` - Match an horizontal whitespace character.
- `(?=.{25,}$)` - Positive lookahead to make sure that there are at least another 25 characters until the end string ancor (to prevent small end-pieces).

Whereas the above pattern would work for lines that are meant as a comment. The only difference with the second pattern is that it uses a negative lookahead to make sure the line doesn't start with literal 'MsgBox('.

---

[image]

My final result:

```
'Some looooooong comment Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
'elit. Ut a volutpat dolor. In risus odio, pharetra a arcu in, efficitur 
'ornare lectus. Maecenas non aliquet leo. Praesent luctus blandit 
'magna, et sagittis ex porta et.
MsgBox("Some text in MsgBox. Donec vulputate eros ac nulla hendrerit auctor. " _
 & "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin fermentum augue elit, eget consequat " _
 & "massa mattis et. Integer semper imperdiet diam sit amet " _
 & "malesuada.", 64, "Title of MsgBox")
'Another comment now with link to doc. 
'https://example.com/?bs64=SWYgeW91IGFyZSBzbWFydCBlbm91Z2ggdG8gZGVjb2RlLCB5b3UgbXVzdCBkZWZpbml0ZWx5IHdhdGNoIHRoaXM6IGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9b0hnNVNKWVJIQTA=
```

Comment: Note that this is quite specific for the piece of code you have mentioned. I agree with @LPChip, it may just be as beneficial to do this manually.

Comment: +1 for how you handled this. :) Nice use of regex.